# Algorithm for solving "Pipes" Game

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I'm looking to create a program to perform a puzzle for me in [a similar fashion as this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSw2HwFZuq0). I have completed the piece searching portion to identify each of the pieces but I'm stuck at where to being to start solving the puzzle.

Backtracking is an option but for very large board sizes it will have high complexity and take time.

Is there any suitable algorithm to solve the game efficiently. Can using heuristics to solve the board help?

Looking for a direction to start.

Comment: The video gives a good overview, but could you formalize the problem a bit? What form will the input be in, what are valid moves, etc?

Comment: The board has some random "dead" spots that occur but otherwise every piece is rotatable 360 degrees and forms connections based on the links of the pieces. The mouse moves the pieces and you can use key/mouse wheel imputs to rotate. When the path is complete you can use the spacebar to enter the path and move to a new board.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand the precise logic of the game you posted. However, if you want something more efficient than DFS/BFS, then you should take a look at A* star: http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/